# How do I POST a CSV Payload to an HTTP upload server?

Tags: mule

I can post a CSV file to an upload site using Postman but cannot do this using Mule. The site is HTTPS but in Postman I've turned SSL cert verify off. I'm using a Content-Type: multipart/form-data. The attachment is called "data" and the file is CSV. This works.

Using Mule it doesn't work here's my snippet.

```
<sub-flow name="upload-content">
        <set-attachment attachmentName="data" value="#[payload]" 
   contentType="application/csv" doc:name="Content Attachment"/>
        <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" 
value="application/multipart/form-data" doc:name="Set Outbound Header"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:request config-ref="my-request-configuration" path="${my.upload.path}" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP Upload"/>
</sub-flow>
```

Here's my error:

Element               : /transaction-history-file/processors/2/upload-content/subprocessors/3 @ prc-transaction-history:service.xml:52 (HTTP Upload)

### Element XML           :

Root Exception stack trace:
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Collections$EmptyIterator.next(Collections.java:4189)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.http.request.NameResolvingRequestBuilder.nextResolvedAddresses(NameResolvingRequestBuilder.java:99)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.http.request.NameResolvingRequestBuilder.setUrl(NameResolvingRequestBuilder.java:75)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient.createGrizzlyRequest(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:545)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient.sendAndWait(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:345)

Can anyone help here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your request config so we can help troubleshoot why you can't connect.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when you are not able to connect to the host.
Check if you need proxy enabled in your application to connect to the host.
Check here https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-10108 this issue occurs this exception you get due to unable to connect the host

Try to check the connection issue. Rest your flows looks fine, just at the end before your HTTP request component set the payload as null :

```
<set-payload value="#[null]"/>
```

and remove :

```
<set-property propertyName="Content-Type" 
value="application/multipart/form-data" doc:name="Set Outbound Header"/>
```

That's it, in `multipart/form-data` everything goes as attachment and body remains null and you don't need to set `set-property`
please do not specify contentType otherwise Mule will not be able to provide the multi-part boundary in the POST.

Comment: Setting the payload to null is not required, it will be ignored if attachments are present.

Comment: @afelisatti If you don't set the payload to null then it doesn't work .. you will not get attachment key name on receiving end... you can try using `#[message.inboundAttachments.keySet()]` on the receiving end which will be null

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the receiving end here will be an external HTTP server, there will be no attachments there, only a `multipart/form-data` request. The `http:request` component will ignore the payload entirely if attachments are present (see https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/modules/http/src/main/java/org/mule/module/http/internal/request/MuleEventToHttpRequest.java#L221) so it's pointless to set the payload to null before it.

Comment: Well, I tried to push the `multipart/form-data` without payload set to null and I realised it is is not ignoring as you said. In fact on the receiving end, I am losing the attachment keys. So, maybe the http request is not acting the way it should be